# SQL Error (1146) in MariaDB when using CTE's and Dynamic SQL. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I have the following query:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT column1, column2, column3
              FROM table 1 ) ,CTE2 AS (SELECT column1, column2, column3
         FROM CTE1 
         WHERE column3 = 1) SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM( CASE WHEN column2 = ''',
      t.column2,
      ''' THEN column3 END)  AS `',
      t.column2, '`'
    )   ) INTO @PivotQuery FROM CTE2 AS t;

SET @PivotQuery = CONCAT('SELECT column1,' ,@PivotQuery, ' 
                         FROM  CTE2 
                         GROUP BY column1');

PREPARE statement FROM @PivotQuery; EXECUTE statement; DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

when executing this query i get the following message:
**SQL Error (1146): Table 'performance_schema.CTE2' doesn't exist**
I have done this type of coding in SQL Server and it works perfectly but when translating it to Mariadb (MySQL) it refuses to work.

INNODB is my storage engine and HeidiSQL is the interface i'm using.

Any clues as to why this wouldn't work?

Comment: CTEs don't exist outside the statement where they are defined. Your attempt would fail in SQL Server as well.

Comment: You are correct. I have been looking at this stuff for too long. How would I go about inserting the results from CTE2 in a temp table in MariaDB. I looked up the documentation and nothing pops up. I know the syntax in SQL server but im fairly new to MariaDB(MySQL)